# Flow running as Guest User for logged-in user

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, error, experience-cloud, guest-user

I have an Experience Cloud site that has several screen flows embedded in it. I'm getting flow errors for multiple flows that say the running user is the site's guest user. There is no way for guest users to access the pages that these flows are on, so I don't know how this is happening.

The errors themselves are either because the guest user doesn't have access to fields that are referenced in the flow or because no ContactId was found in relation to the user.

> No such column 'Published_to_Portal__c'

> This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: Vaccine_Manufacturer__c FROM Contact WHERE ((Id = ''))

The site is technically public, but there are only a few pages that are open to the public. The rest of the pages are inaccessible to the public. I just locked down the flow components themselves by assigning an audience for authenticated users, so maybe that will help.

I'm worried that my real logged-in community users are experiencing flow errors and I can't track them down. Has anyone else experienced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The Flows could be triggered by user action on the site even if the guest user can't see the specific pages.

- Check the context that your Flows run in (system or user). You may choose to run the Flows in system context to avoid such errors
- You could add a check at the beginning of the Flow not to execute if $User.{Profile} = "Guest User"